# setting default value in dropdown select in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html-select

In my view I have something like...

```
<select id="conSelect" name="conSelect" ng-model="conSelect" 
    ng-options="place.PlaceID as place.PlaceName for place in places"
    ng-change="onCountryChange(conSelect)">
</select>
```

where 'places' is datasource from which i am populating dropdown. It shows the values. But It shows blank value as first value of dropown. How, do I set value=0 and text="--select--" as a first value in dropdown and not the blank value.

Comment: You can use placeholder

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a default option like so:

```
<select id="conSelect" name="conSelect" ng-model="conSelect" ng-options="place.PlaceID as place.PlaceName for place in places" ng-change="onCountryChange(conSelect)" >
    <option value="0">--select--</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've broken your question down into two parts:

> How do I set value=0

I assume you mean `<option value="0"`.  This sounds like a bad idea.  I suspect you do not need to try to do that.

> How do I set text="--select--"

Default options are done with an empty value.  Angular will interpret this a your default option and not as a real value.

```
<select id="conSelect" name="conSelect" ng-model="conSelect" 
    ng-options="place.PlaceID as place.PlaceName for place in places"
    ng-change="onCountryChange(conSelect)">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry ur answer works... value="" works instead of value="0".... so issue got solved

Comment: @ghetal  OK, cool thanks.  In that case please don't forget to upvote and click the green tick next to your accepted answer.

Comment: ` <option value="">--select--</option>` default value is not working for me